# How can enable the "Copy-paste" menu in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I worked with editText in Android, but when i want select,copy or paste text/number inside of ediTText it's impossible,that is to say, if I pressing (Long press) don't show the menu to select "paste" or anything.
The code from my xml file (EditText) is the next:

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
    android:id="@+id/titulo_articulo_periodico"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:hint="@string/periodico_hint1"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    app:met_primaryColor="@color/refresco"
    app:met_clearButton="true"/>
```

I work with "Material EditText" library (github: https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) but I don't see difference between my code and the owner code, my friend tell me than i need use onActionItemClicked in every editText, but with this code my Java code is too long. I don't know what do, I'm tired. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no short way of doing it. You have to use Clipboard Manager, And have a lengthy way of implementing the functionality. I am still looking for a simple solution to this. until then refer this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html